# Finding the intersection between 2 lines using matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-programming

My professor uploaded some notes, and there's a step in his explanation of a Linear Programming Problem which I do not understand. He takes 2 lines and converts them into matrices in order to find the intersection point.

Can someone explain what steps he is performing here? I know how to find the intersection by making the equations equal each other, but not this method.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like he's performing elementary row operations; for example, the first he does is switch the rows while dividing the (originally) first row by $2$, and the second he subtracts $7$ times the (now) first row from the second row, then finally divides the (now) second row by $-40$.